# How to upload an image through copy / paste using django modelform?

Tags: django, google-apps-script, django-forms, modelform

I'm pretty new with django, and trying to migrate a google apps script (GAS) webapp to django.

One feature I had on google website was to capture a pasted image from clipboard and submit it through a form. That was done through a hidden field in the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="summaryImage" id='summaryImage' value=''>
```

and then I capture the paste event to populate this hidden form field

```
/* Handle paste events */
function pasteHandler(e) {
   if (e.clipboardData) {
      // Get the items from the clipboard
      var items = e.clipboardData.items;
      if (items) {
         // Loop through all items, looking for any kind of image
         for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (items[i].type.indexOf("image") !== -1) {
               // We need to represent the image as a file,
               var blob = items[i].getAsFile();
               var URLObj = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
               var source = URLObj.createObjectURL(blob);
               var reader = new FileReader();
               reader.onload = function(e) {
                 document.getElementById("summaryImage").value= reader.result;
               }
               reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
            } 
          }
      }
   } 
}
```

The above form when submitted through google, can be parsed on the server side google apps script (GAS) from the summaryImage field in the form, like below:

```
var splitBase = form.summaryImage.split(','),
var type = splitBase[0].split(';')[0].replace('data:','');
var byteCharacters = Utilities.base64Decode(splitBase[1]);
var blob = Utilities.newBlob(byteCharacters, type);
```

Now, in django, I am having trouble replicating this. I have created a model with a ImageField in models.py:

```
...
image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Image')
...
```

And set the widget to HiddenInput() in forms.py

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = myModel
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'image': forms.HiddenInput()
        }
    ...
```

And when captured the paste even, I set it to this hidden image field:

```
document.getElementById("id_image").value= reader.result;
```

But then I could not submit the form, getting an error message:

> (Hidden field image) No file was submitted. Check the encoding type on
>   the form.

I searched quite a bit but could not find any mentioning about capturing pasted image from clipboard in django. Is this even doable?

Comment: In the html you have input type hidden and not image. I guess the Django form should have a CharField to accept the pasted data. In the form clean and save method you convert that string data to a file object and use that to populate the ImageField.

Comment: @allcaps Thanks!! it does seem to work and captured the data as a string.  It looks like this: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABUAAAAWCAYAAAAvg9c4AAAAMUlEQVRIDWP8////fwYqAyYqmwc2btRQ6ofqaJiOhimVQ2A0SVE5QBkYGEbDdIiEKQC6hwQozNWIkwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==

Comment: @allcaps, but I guess will need a bigger field to hold image and CharField maxlength is not enough. I'll try textarea. Is there a better way / field type to capture this data?

Comment: No, add the charfield to the form not to the model. From the form docs on charfield: `Validates max_length or min_length, if they are provided. Otherwise, all inputs are valid.`. So you do not need a textarea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @allcaps's suggestions, I figured out the solution.

Basically I kept the ImageField (image) in my model, and assigned a custom widget to only display it with id `id_image`. Then added a hidden input field `image_container` in the form to receive the pasted data. The save function of the form is overridden to create the file and save it back to the ImageField.

```
class PictureWidget(forms.widgets.Widget):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        if str(value) == '':
            html1 = "<img id='id_image' style='display:block' class='rounded float-left d-block'/>"
        else:
            html1 = "<img id='id_image' style='display:block' class='rounded float-left d-block' src='" + settings.MEDIA_URL + str(value) + "'/>"
        return mark_safe(html1)

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    image_container = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    class Meta:
        model = MYMODEL
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'image': PictureWidget(),
        }
    def save(self, commit=True):
        # check image_container data
        self.instance.image.delete(False)
        imgdata = self.cleaned_data['image_container'].split(',')
        try:
            ftype = imgdata[0].split(';')[0].split('/')[1]
            fname = slugify(self.instance.title)
            self.instance.image.save('path/%s.%s' % (fname, ftype), ContentFile(imgdata[1].decode("base64")))
        except:
            pass
        return super(MyForm, self).save(commit=commit)
```